# Best way to solve system of quadratic forms

Tags: nonlinear-equations

I have a system of equations that have the following structure. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and let $x_k$ be the $k$-th element of $x$. Let $H_k\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ for $k=1,\ldots, m$. I need to find the $x$ satisfying,
\begin{align}
x_k = x^\top H_k x
\end{align}
for $k=1,\ldots,m$. I know that I can solve this system via fixed point iteration or via Newton's method. Are these the best ways? Are there non-iterative methods?

Comment: Do you have any assumption you can do on $H_k$? For example, if it's tridiagonal then you can for sure improve.

Comment: I would be okay assuming that $H_k$ is invertible but otherwise doesn't have special structure.

Comment: Are you willing to assume that $H_{k}$ is symmetric? positive definite?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Okay, let's say symmetry but not necessarily positive definite.